# How To Make a Phone Call with Button click in Recyclerview

Tags: java, jquery, android-studio, android-recyclerview

i want use the method `ACTION_CALL` . the problem is when i click the button of the first cardview the app call the phone number `11111111` . & when i click the button of the second card view the app call  also the same number `1111111`.
what i want is when i click the button of the first cardview it call `111111`
and when i click on the button of the second cardview it  call `22222222`

item layout xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
app:contentPaddingBottom="50dp"
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
card_view:cardElevation="6dp"

>

<RelativeLayout
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp">


    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#7f89e9"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contact1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtCelebName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtCelebName"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtCelebMovie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCelebName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />





    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="............"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage" />



    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/phonegreen"

        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonfordialog"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter :

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

private List<Celebrity> celebrityList;
private final View.OnClickListener btnListener;

public ItemAdapter(List<Celebrity> celebrityList, View.OnClickListener btnListener) {
    this.celebrityList = celebrityList;
    this.btnListener = btnListener;
}

@Override
public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);

    return new ItemHolder(itemView, btnListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    Celebrity item = celebrityList.get(position);
    holder.txtCelebName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.txtCelebMovie.setText(item.getFamousMovie());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return celebrityList.size();
}

public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    private  Button buttoncalling;
    public TextView txtCelebName, txtCelebMovie;
    public ImageView profileImage;

    public ItemHolder(View view, View.OnClickListener btnListener) {
        super(view);
        txtCelebName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCelebName);
        txtCelebMovie = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCelebMovie);
        profileImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        buttoncalling  = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfordialog);
        buttoncalling.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
    }
}
```

}

Main java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            a_builder.setCancelable(false);
            a_builder.setMessage("do you want to call this person!!!");
            a_builder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:11111111111"));



                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                    }
                });


            a_builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
            alert.setTitle("Alert !");
            alert.show();



        }
        };






    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.MyToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Service/DPNG");


    ArrayList<Celebrity> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    fillDummyData(itemList);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, btnListener);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
}

private void fillDummyData(ArrayList<Celebrity> celebList) {
    Celebrity celeb1 = new Celebrity();
    celeb1.setName("Johny.D");
    celeb1.setFamousMovie("Pirates  ");
    celeb1.setProfilePhotoLocation("@drawable/contact1");
    celebList.add(celeb1);

    Celebrity celeb2 = new Celebrity();
    celeb2.setName("Arnold");
    celeb2.setFamousMovie("The Terminator");
    celeb2.setProfilePhotoLocation("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI3MDc4NzUyMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTQyMTc5MQ@@._V1._SY209_CR13,0,140,209_.jpg");
    celebList.add(celeb2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I hope someone may find this answer useful:

- First of all, you're hard-coding the number to call in your button listener. Hence, whatever button you click on, you're asking it to make a call to 1111111.
- What you need to do is to add a field in your Celebrity class for a phone number. Then in your adapter, create an interface that will be implemented in your MainActivity class. Thus, on click of an item (which in this case is a cardview), you retrieve the phone number of the celebrity, and feed that to your implemented interface where you make the call to the celebrity.
- Doing so, you'll be retrieving the right phone number for each celebrity instead of using the hard-coded string you currently have.

Adapter:

```
public interface CardClickListener {
   onCardClicked(Celebrity celebrity);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemAdapter.CardClickListener {
......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

........

// add the following to your onCreate method 
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Celebrity celebrity = itemList.get(position);
            onCardClicked(celebrity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
.........
}

// implement your interface here
@Override
public void onCardClicked(Celebrity celebrity) {
   // don't forget to check for permissions
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + celebrity.phone));
}

......

// add phone numbers to your class definitions
private void fillDummyData(ArrayList<Celebrity> celebList) {
   Celebrity celeb1 = new Celebrity();
   celeb1.setName("Johny.D");
   celeb1.setFamousMovie("Pirates  ");
   celeb1.setPhone("111111");
   celeb1.setProfilePhotoLocation("@drawable/contact1");
   celebList.add(celeb1);

   Celebrity celeb2 = new Celebrity();
   celeb2.setName("Arnold");
   celeb2.setFamousMovie("The Terminator");
   celeb2.setPhone("222222");
   celeb2.setProfilePhotoLocation("http://ia.mediaimdb.com/images/M/209_.jpg");
   celebList.add(celeb2);
}
} //mainactivity
```

RecyclerTouchListener:

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
```

}

ClickListener:

```
public interface ClickListener {
  void onClick(View view, int position);

  void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
```